# operator module and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, operators

I would like to allow the user to input an operator.  Is it possible to use the operator module to select values in a pandas dataframe?
I've tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import operator

In [7]: df=pd.DataFrame(ab,columns=['numbers','letters'])

In [8]: print(df)
   numbers letters
0       10       a
1        5       b
2        8       c
3       11       d
4       15       e
```

I've tried this to get all values <10:

```
df1=operator.lt(df[df['numbers'],10])
```

But I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I'm new to pandas and am wondering if I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not df[df['numbers'].lt(10)]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the DataFrame indexing after the operator call:

```
df1=df[operator.lt(df['numbers'],10)]
```

Because `operator.lt` returns a [boolean Series, which can be used by `df[...]` as index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). It's called [boolean array indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

However, if you don't actually need the operator module you could just write:

```
df[df['numbers'] < 10]
```